# Alfresco incapable of previewing text files including japanese characters

Tags: alfresco, preview, alfresco-share

I have been customizing the Alfresco 4.0d Community version and used "Share" for document management.
Now I am facing the document previewing problem in document detail page. After uploading a text file including japanese characters encoded character set with UTF-8, the file shows on the preview is garbled. Janpanese characters in text file are not displayed correctly on the preview.
But preview for Excel, Word and Pdf document types is okay and can be previewed correctly. This problem is only occurred in plain text file previewing.
My current development environments are as followings:
Alfresco Version: 4.0 d Community Edition
OS : Cent OS 5.5
Web Server :Apache Tomcat 6.0.35
Database Server: PostgreSQL 8.4
Browsers: IE8, Firefox 30
Browser Addon: Adobe Shockwave Flash Object 14.0.0.176
So, let me know that Is there a way to solve this problem.Any help, would be much appreciated.

Comment: In Alfresco share where the japanese text is in, can you check what font style it is using by clicking part of the japanese text?

Comment: Japanese text is inside the file.This file is uploaded by Share page.Used MS PGothic font for japanese text and character set is UTF-8.

Comment: By document previewing, you mean the **Edit Properties** option in Alfresco Share, right? And in the Content section?

Comment: No,  I mean that file is created outside by notepad text editor and uploaded to Share.

Comment: this may be an server os and/or db isse. I've never tried but also the text to pdf transformer is not able to handle jp characters?